# Inserting data into db with python

Tags: python, mysql, json

Im inserting data into a table with python web server. im able to send information to get inserted using an ajax call

```
{
  "verb":"addPerson",
  "person":{
            "name":"what this",
            "email":"whatis@gmail"
  }
}

def addPerson(model, request):
    person = request["person"]
    print person
    return database.insertObj(person, "users")
```

print person will print this

```
{u'name': u'what this', u'email': u'whatis@gmail'}
```

.

```
def insertObj(obj, tableName):

    d = dict(obj)  

    # Write SQL Query
    query = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})"
    columns = ','.join(d.keys())
    placeholders = ','.join(['"%s"'] * len(d))
    sql = query.format(tableName, columns, placeholders) % tuple(d.values())

    # Run It and Handle Error
    dbResponse = executeSQL(sql)

    if ("error" in dbResponse) : return dbResponse

    else :
        cursor = dbResponse["cursor"]
        response = {"newId": cursor.lastrowid}
        cursor.close() 
        config.conn.commit()
        return response
```

But when i create my own object in python it returns an mysql error

```
def test(model, request):
    fromUser = request['username']
    toUser = request["name"]
    fromQuery = "SELECT * FROM users where name='{}' LIMIT 1".format(fromUser)
    toQuery = "SELECT * FROM users where name='{}' LIMIT 1".format(toUser)
    logRequest = {
        'from':str(fromUser),
        'too_number':str(database.get_row(toQuery)['telephone']),
        'too':str(toUser),
        'from_number':str(database.get_row(fromQuery)['telephone']),
        'time':str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
        'responded':'false'
    }
    print logRequest
    print database.insertObj(logRequest, "requests")
```

heres what it returns

> {'error': 'MySQL Error: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near \'from,too,time,too_number,responded)
>   VALUES ("private-data","Dawson Spencer","Daws\' at line 1'}

Is my error in logRequest? if so how would i fix this?

Comment: Can you print the `sql` query before `executeSQL()`?

Comment: Don't use `.format()` on SQL queries! It will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use the function offered by the database adapter to parameterize your query!